# Simple Java Query - Getting a Result from a String

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I have been trying to learn Java for the past few days so my my knowledge is incredibly basic.

I cannot for the life of me work out how to search for the answer to my question online.

I am trying to create a very simple currency converter. The user inputs a currency symbol, then using an IF statement I want to specify the value of 'currencyamnt'

I want to essenially

```
if ( currency = "£"  )

    {
        currencyamnt = 1;
    }
```

currency being a string and currencyamnt being an float.

This doesnt work and i am not sure why..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java you have to use the .equals to check if a string is equal to some other string. In something like c++ this is valid but for java instead of doing this:

```
if ( currency == "£"  ) {
    currencyamnt = 1;
}
```

try

```
if ( currency.equals("£")) {
    currencyamnt = 1;
}
```

**Edit:** 
The original code looked like this:

```
if ( currency = "£"  ) {
    currencyamnt = 1;
}
```

Which would have set currency to £ instead of checking whether it was equivalent text which is something to always look out for when coding!

Comment: I have to wait another 10 mins before I am allowed to accept answer so will do then

Comment: Thanks! and check the last edit that I just added about the = vs == since you should watch out for things like that when coding!

Answer (score 1):

currency.equals("£") should do it.